# I am getting the following error while importing VGGFace on Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

```
from keras_vggface.vggface import VGGFace

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-965cbf01fa40> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import tensorflow
      2 
----> 3 from keras_vggface.vggface import VGGFace
      4 
      5 #from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_vggface/models.py in <module>
     14     AveragePooling2D, Reshape, Permute, multiply
     15 from keras_applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
---> 16 from keras.utils import layer_utils
     17 from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
     18 from keras import backend as K

ImportError: cannot import name 'layer_utils' from 'keras.utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried multiple versions of the tensorflow and keras but no luck.